# creating url to use instead of ip address for aolserver used in project open

Tags: http, tcl, openacs, project-open, aolserver

In Project-Open tool, aolserver is used to host the application and is accessed using the ip address of the server like 172.XX.XX.XX:8000.
Now I don't want to make this ip address public. I tried to create and use url (by making some changes in the config.tcl ) for this but couldn't do so.

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough.

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm uncertain what “make this address public” means. I freely admit to not knowing aolserver very well…

Comment: "make this address public”= don't want every user of the application to know the ip address as it is against security policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your question isn't totally clear, but I think what you want is for your website to appear on a URL, such as www.example.com. To do this with AOLserver, you need to edit the /web/server/etc/config.tcl file and edit this line (changing www.example.com to whatever URL you want).

```
set hostname              www.example.com
```

Then restart AOLserver. You might also want to set the port to 80. This requires root access, and you may also need to pass -b to AOLserver in your startup script.

Comment: how to set the port to 8000?
what about the "set adress " variable.?

Comment: From what you've said, the port is already set to 8000. If you wish to change it, edit the line "set httpport". The "set address" is used to set the IP address that your server listens on. Set it to 0.0.0.0 to test your server.

Comment: You can also use firewall/NAT rules to make the service appear to be on port 80 without having to grant extra permissions (by mapping one port to another). I've never written such a rule myself, though I'm sure you can find out how through looking on Stack Overflow or Server Fault.

Comment: Hi Brian,
I change the "Set hostname" parameter to the desired url as per your suggestion,But still it's not working.Please help!!!

Comment: @Victor Look in the error.log. Is there a line like this? [02/Jan/2014:14:54:02][15981.1092684128][-nssock:driver-] Notice: nssock: listen
ing on 0.0.0.0:8160

Comment: @Brian..yes. the last line is similar to it just that the port no is 8000 instead of 8160.

Comment: Well then you should be able to access it from www.example.com:8000 If not, you may have a firewall or network rule that's blocking it.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are running ]project-open[ on a local server on port 8000 and you want to make this service visible to the Internet, right? There are several steps required:

1. In your Internet router, you will need to open a port (80 or 8000).
2. You need to forward incoming traffic on your router to the ]project-open[ server. You can do this using a forwarding rule or similar. Please check your router.
3. You probably want to setup a URL using DynDns, Dynu or other DNS providers pointing to your Internet router, and changing in case your router's IP is also changing (SOHO router).
4. In ]po[ you will need to set the redirection URL accordingly. Depending on the port, you may want to set Admin -> Parameters -> "SuppressHTTPPort" to 1

Answer (score 0):

Which OS will you be using to access this server?  If you will be using a LInux machine you would put the host name into your /etc/host file with the desired name:

For example:

/etc/hosts:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.23.108 myprojecturl
```

The line 192.168.23.108 will provide for you to use myprojecturl to access the site rather than the ip number 192.168.23.108 (from that machine).

From a Windows machine you could do the same.  The host file is located in a different plaice ().

c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
192.168.23.108 myprojecturl
```

The last line is an example of what you would add to make "myprojecturl" the host name for pulling up the site instead of having to remember the ip numbers to type in.

Comment: Os of the server in Linux(centos6).
what about the port?
this application runs on port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make generated urls be different from the where the server is listening, you need to set the `location` parameter in the nssock configuration.

in the config fie is a section like this:

```
ns_section ns/server/${server}/module/nssock
    ns_param   timeout            120
    ns_param   address            $address
    ns_param   hostname           $hostname
    ns_param   port               $httpport
```

Add in

```
    ns_param   location    http://my.host.com/
```

see http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.aolserver/month=20110201